# Queries to print questions and their choices

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a survey/multiple choice thing in PHP+MySQL. I've created two tables so far: questions and choices. Each question has a unique primary key question_id, and each choice has a foreign key question_id.

I want to print a list of all questions with their corresponding choices. My PHP is a little rusty, so I can't remember the correct way to do this. Do I just run a query to select all questions, and run a query to select the choices for each question as it is selected? Or can it be done with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Some psuedo SQL:

```
select * from
(Select question_id, question_text from table_questions) questions
join
(Select parent_question_id, choice_text from table_choices) choices
on
questions.question_id=choices.parent_question_id
```

You will have to alter the above depending on your setup- you may also need a different [JOIN type](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Different_Join_Types.htm)

Once connected to your database in PHP, you can run through the results as so:

```
$sql="select * from
(Select question_id, question_text from table_questions) questions
join
(Select parent_question_id, choice_text from table_choices) choices
on
questions.question_id=choices.parent_question_id";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $question_and_answers[$db_field['question_text']][]=$db_field['choice_text'];
}

print_r($question_and_answers);
```

This will output/create an array of questions, with sub array's of choices.

Comment: What's going on with answers? I just want it to print the questions possible choices, as it's a multiple choice thing.

Comment: @Matt, please see the revision

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return all questions:

SELECT questions.*, choices.* from questions join choices using (question_id);

Then iterate through the results, e.g. copying all the necessary data on the choices into an array keyed by the question_id; then use this data structure to build the form widgets etc.

Not sure if that is what you're looking for - hard to provide a more helpful response without knowing where you are stuck.